# opening a popup at marker's click and loading another Angular component as popup's content

Tags: angular, leaflet

I need to show at a marker click the content of another angular component passing an id of the marker to as parameter... I've found no working solution... till the point I show simple html everything works..

currently my code is

```
  var component = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(MainPostCardComponent);

    marker.bindPopup(L.popup(
    component
    ));


    marker.bindPopup(component.location.nativeElement);
    marker.on('click', function (e) {
      if (this.currentSelectedMarker != null) {
        
        console.log("found previous item, resetting color");
        this.currentSelectedMarker.setIcon( new svgIcon);
      }//
     // marker.setIcon( new  svgSelectedIcon);
       this.currentSelectedMarker = marker;

     
      marker.openPopup();

      

    });
```

But this doens't work... any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the bindpopup function you can only insert html